# My code works on small devices but its not working on large screen devices above 5' inch

Tags: android, xml-layout, binary-xml

My code works on small devices but it doesn't work on large screen devices above 5 inches.

The layout folders structure is the following:

```
layout-land/homeactivity.xml
layout-small-land/homeactivity.xml
layout-large-land/homeactivity.xml
layout-xlarge-land/homeactivity.xml
```

And the exception is:

```
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pelkin.peekzoo/com.pelkin.peekzoo.Animals}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class 
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647) 
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
```

Comment: There should be more information in the exception - like *where* the `NullPointerException` occurs.

Comment: Yea you need to provide more than this for anybody to be able to help you.

Comment: u need to keep one `layout` folder as the base for any unhandled screens size

Comment: it is in HomeActivity class which is an Activity.

Comment: 12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pelkin.peekzoo/com.pelkin.peekzoo.Animals}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-17 12:26:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all ids of every view in all xml. It should be same in all xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have all of the images you use in all different sizes? If you're missing icons or images in the bigger sizes: drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xhdpi, this might give you a nullpointer. Since it is trying to load an image wich doesn't exist in that size.

Comment: I dont think this will create the null pointer exception , since if the images are there in other drawable folders it will take the source from it

Comment: @Black Magic My image structure is as follows:
drawable-land
drawable-land-hdpi
drawable-land-xhdpi
drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-land-ldpi

I only put all images in ldpi and hdpi

Answer (score 0):

the ID might be different in layout-large-land/homeactivity.xml or
layout-xlarge-land/homeactivity.xml of the layout. double check your id's.

Comment: Thnx man its working, i have not copied my buttons code in all xml :)